# SELECT two variables in SQL, one with a WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I have a table with votes: **id** is the person who voted, **vote** = 1 is the fact that he participated, and **num** is the number of vote.

I would like to select two variables from the same query, and one `WHERE` conditions would apply to only one variable. These two variables should be `GROUP BY` the same date, using `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`.

This is a sample of the initial table:

```
+----+------------+------+-----+
| id |    date    | vote | num |
+----+------------+------+-----+
|  1 | 2018-01-25 |    1 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-01-25 |    1 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-01-25 |    1 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-01-25 |    1 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-01-25 |    1 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-01-25 |    1 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-01-25 |    1 |   1 |
|  1 | 2017-12-25 |    1 |   2 |
|  2 | 2017-12-25 |    1 |   2 |
|  5 | 2017-12-25 |    1 |   2 |
|  2 | 2017-11-20 |    1 |   3 |
|  3 | 2017-11-20 |    1 |   3 |
|  5 | 2017-11-20 |    1 |   3 |
|  6 | 2017-11-20 |    1 |   3 |
|  7 | 2017-11-20 |    1 |   3 |
+----+------------+------+-----+
```

I would like to have, in the same query, the `SUM()` of **vote** by month and by year and `WHERE id = 1` for instance; and the `COUNT(DISTINCT(())` of the votes (**num**), by month and by year.

The idea would be to have, for every month, the number of time a person (**id**) have voted and the number of votes there have been. Like this example, if we select **id** = 2.

```
+----+-------+------+---------------+-------+
| id | month | year | participation | total |
+----+-------+------+---------------+-------+
|  2 |     1 | 2018 |             0 |     1 |
|  2 |    12 | 2017 |             0 |     1 |
|  2 |    11 | 2017 |             1 |     1 |
+----+-------+------+---------------+-------+
```

All the queries that I have tried are not good.

Comment: you say that you select `id=1` but your output returns `id=2`. Please update your expected output.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Can someone have a num without participating ?

Comment: @Krishna yes sorry I wanted to use id=1 at the beginning but changed to have the idea that, sometimes, a person does not vote, even when there are votes in the chamber.

Comment: @Strawberry, actually, in my MYSQL database (parsed from opendata XML files), there's only a line when a person votes. Therefore, I have coded the col vote = 1 when he or she votes. When there is a vote (num=35 for vote number 35) and the person does not vote, then there is no line for him or her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking for.

Please provide current query you have and expected result set.

So far here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29cc07/6

```
SELECT id,
      YEAR(`date`) `year`,
      MONTH(`date`) `month`,
      SUM(vote),
      SUM(num)
FROM votes
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY id, `year`, `month`
ORDER BY `year`, `month`
```

**UPDATE** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29cc07/21

```
SELECT id,
      v_ym.year,
      v_ym.month,
      SUM(vote),
      COUNT(DISTINCT(num))
FROM (
 SELECT  
      YEAR(`date`) `year`,
      MONTH(`date`) `month`
 FROM votes
 GROUP BY `year` ASC, `month` ASC
) v_ym
LEFT JOIN votes v
ON MONTH(v.`date`) = v_ym.month
   AND YEAR(v.`date`) = v_ym.year
   AND v.id = 2
GROUP BY id, v_ym.year,      v_ym.month
 ORDER BY `year` ASC, `month` ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for this (I've updated it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29cc07/9). The only problem I have with that query is that, if there is a vote and the person does not vote, I have no line for him in my database. Therefore the result does not display the month if he does not vote during this given month. As I tried to show it the result I'd like in my initial post, if I have no line for a person during a given month, then this person will not be displayed in the result. But I do not think it is feasible, I think I'll have to change my database, don't know how :)

Comment: too many words. provide dataset in sqlfiddle and provide expected resultset with any parameters value you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for the update. The new query displays the line for a person, even though he does not vote during a given month. Yet is it possible to have in any cases the number of votes that has taken place during this month? In other words, the `WHERE v.id = x` statement would only apply column `SUM(vote)`?

Comment: @AwenigMarié I can't get your question. you have SUM and COUNT - do whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

```
select year(date) year, month(date) month, sum(vote) vote_sum, sum(distinct num) distinct_num_sum
from t as t1
where id = 1
group by year(date), month(date)
```

You can see it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6420fb7/27).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Like I said to others, I would have liked to display a data even when there is no, which is not feasible. I need to change the database, or maybe adapt a PHP code that comes after my query.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently solved this issue, unfortunately for you, my skill set is tsql, not mysql. I can explain how to solve the issue from a logical point of view, but I can't solve it for mysql with an exact code example.

The biggest part of your issue is you're expecting data where there is none. In your example you're expecting a record count (0) where there is no record. You must first conjure up a record.

Changing a null record to a 0 is do-able if you first have the record.

That is ID with an aggregation for a month and year, an easier approach is to just leave the day value at 1, rather than splitting out the month and year.

You need your source data to include:

```
+----+------------+------+-----+
| id |    date    | vote | num |
+----+------------+------+-----+
2      01-01-2018   null   null
```

First step is to create the date, in tsql you can do something like this:

```
declare @date as table (
    DateID int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   StartDate date not null
,   EndDate date not null
);

insert into @date (StartDate, EndDate)

select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -1)), eomonth(sysdatetime()) union all
select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -2)), eomonth(sysdatetime(), -1) union all
select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -3)), eomonth(sysdatetime(), -2) union all
select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -4)), eomonth(sysdatetime(), -3) union all
select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -5)), eomonth(sysdatetime(), -4) union all
select dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(sysdatetime(), -6)), eomonth(sysdatetime(), -5)
```

this will give you a result set something like:

```
1 2018-01-01    2018-01-31
2 2017-12-01    2017-12-31
3 2017-11-01    2017-11-30
```

you might have noticed I have two columns there, this is to find the beginning and end date of a month, this allows you to join on a date range, tossing out the complexity of using an integer for month and year.

Provided your IDs are arbitrary you could create an ID and date, and then just join however if your ID value is more complex, you'll need to use a cross apply to apply the date to your ID.

The code should look something like:

```
     ;with cte as (
    select *
      from MyDataTable a
      cross apply
        (
            select *
              from @date b
        ) x
    )

    select ID
         , RealDateDate
         , FirstOfMonthDate
         , EndOfMonthDate
      from cte a
 left join MyDataTable b
        on a.ID = a.ID
       and b.date between a.FirstOfMonthDate and a.EndOfMonthDate;
```

Then you should be able to run your aggregations on that result set to get the results you are looking.

You should be able to get your result set based off your select query to look something like this:

```
+----+------------+------+-----+
| id |    date    | vote | num |
+----+------------+------+-----+
|  1 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |   1 |
|  5 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |   1 |
|  1 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |   1 |
|  3 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |   1 |
|  4 | 2018-01-01 |    1 |   1 |
|  2 | 2018-01-01 |  null| null|
```

then you use functions such as `isnull(vote, 0)` ... this is where your nulls turn into 0s.

Comment: Thanks for the -1, please completely read and comprehend the solution prior to voting. Could you go ahead and post the errors my code generates in mysql?

Comment: Table declaration won't work because IDENTITY(1, 1) doesn't exist in MySQL.  The `INSERT` clause won't work because EOMONTH() doesn't exist in MySQL.  CTE won't work because it doesn't exist in MySQL.  Practically none of the statement works, thus the -1.

Comment: Thank you for this. Indeed the result is the one I would have like. And I understand this does not seem to be possible with MySQL. Thanks any way.

Comment: @Eric +1 for second comment